# Is it currently possible to display an html element outside browser viewport and make it visible to the user in the device viewport?

Tags: javascript, html, css, browser

I would like to make an app where the user can draw something on the device viewport (on the compute screen) the drawing is then displayed on a big screen

In the app,

the user would be able to move the drawing element to place it in the device viewport
the drawing element would have to be displayed on the big screen (outside browser viewport)

Is that possible?

Comment: You will probably have to send the data to whatever device is in control of what gets displayed on the "big screen" then.

Comment: Do you mean that you have 2 screens, and that you want to work on one screen and show results on the other one ? If yes, then you only need to open a new browser's window on the second screen.